# Interference of canvas items and problem in setting coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, anchor, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on an animation of a moving object, while drawing it's path.
I want to draw the pixels in which the center of the object went through... but guess what? python decided to set the NW anchor of the image with the coordinates I send, instead of the center. I infer it has something to do with the pixels I draw simultaneously (creating a one pixel rectangle). so the image appear on the right of the path bellow...  I want the center of it to be on the top of the pixels... adding the main of the code:

```
from tkinter import*
import time

dt = 0.01
clock_place = (500, 10)


def round_two(t, t0):
    return round((t-t0)*100)/100


def round_three(t, t0):
    return round((t-t0)*1000)/1000


# showing 'real time motion' for a known path (also cyclic), with
# parametric representation

def paint_known_path(x_pos, y_pos, t_0):
    window = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(window, height=700, width=1000)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.config(background='black')
    tennis_ball = PhotoImage(file='tennis ball.png')

    t = t_0
    x = x_pos(t_0)
    y = y_pos(t_0)
    particle = canvas.create_image(x, y, image=tennis_ball)
    clock = canvas.create_text(clock_place, text=round_two(t, t_0), 
    fill='white')
    while True:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x, y, outline='red')
        canvas.itemconfig(clock, text=round_two(t, t_0))
        t += dt
        x = x_pos(t)
        y = y_pos(t)
        canvas.moveto(particle, x, y)
        window.update()
        if x == x_pos(t_0) and y == y_pos(t_0):
            if t - t_0 > 100*dt:
                break
        time.sleep(dt)

    canvas.create_text((500, 100), text='orbit duration: ' + 
    str(round_three(t, t_0)), fill='white')
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: that is because the canvas item, such as rectangle, is defined from the corner. in order to get the centre point you need to move half the object width across...

Comment: Also please add code in a way that works.  presume this needs `import tkinter` and the `canvas` object.  `t_0`, `x_pos()` etc. are all not defined...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you for the comment, I am new to this site... when I try adding this image item to the canvas, while the default is anchor='CENTER', it works just fine.
for some reason here it places the image coords according to NW anchor, no matter what anchor I set...

Comment: added the full code. x_pos is any function of t, same for y_pos

Comment: Try using `canvas.coords(particle, x, y)` instead of `canvas.moveto(particle, x, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be quite a bit require, but here is the main completion components.

The first additional part that you need to add:

```
# print('the ten ball height', tennis_ball.height(), tennis_ball.width())
# tennis ball dimensions
tb_hght = tennis_ball.height()
tb_wdth = tennis_ball.width()
mid_point_x = x + tennis_ball.height() / 2
mid_point_y = y + tennis_ball.width() / 2
```

Secondly, also needed to add some functions to for `x_pos` and `y_pos` like this (these are just example functions to make the code work):

```
def x_pos(a):
    # any function of t,
    return 100

def y_pos(a):
    # any function of t,
    return 100
```

Furthermore, you need to call the function at the end like this:

```
paint_known_path(x_pos,y_pos,0)
```

Finally, need to add the `mid_point_x` and `mid_point_y` to the path that is drawn (as these will be the image centre points).

Comment: And one final comment:  It is better practice to `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import*`. This way, it becomes easier to identify the `tk` module components.